# Scala Style Guide: Why Mimic a function?

Tags: scala

I’m reading the Scala style guide:  http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html

and they mention this:

> **Objects**
>
> Objects follow the class naming convention (camelCase with a
>   capital first letter) except when attempting to mimic a package or a
>   function. These situations don’t happen often, but can be expected in
>   general development.:

```
object ast {
  sealed trait Expr
  case class Plus(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
  ...
}
object inc {
  def apply(x: Int): Int = x + 1
}
```

I can think of maybe a few thin use cases for the "object ast".  But I can't think of why anyone would want to "mimic a function" in the manner of "object inc".  It feels a bit unconventional, and likely to confuse other developers.

Are there any example cases where the core Scala libraries do this?  Or when would it be good practice to define a function like this?

Comment: That's what `shapeless.Poly` does for example: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, one good example is [shapeless.Poly](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values) functions.

A `Poly` function is a polymorphic version of a function. It needs to be represented as an object for three main reasons:

- it contains multiple functions (to handle multiple cases, since they're polymorphic)
- an object's companion object is the object itself. This allows for defining the various cases as implicit methods inside the object and have them picked up by the compiler
- [objects provide a stable identifier](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shapeless-dev/P5DXRgnzqkY), so the compiler won't complain when passing the instance of the function to any of shapeless's methods

Technicalities aside, they're conceptually functions, hence the same naming style for regular functions is used.

Comment: Thanks - I've never used that area of Shapeless - it seems like a feasible use case

Comment: "Technicalities aside, they're conceptually functions, hence the same naming style for regular functions is used." This is the key insight. It is about  being able to abstract.